# Filter is returning a table with no data

Tags: r, data-science

Im trying to filter the rows with Brinks, its returning a table with no data. The select function is working, i ran it and it selected the data. When running the filter function it does not  work, any help it welcome thank you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
SU<- read_excel("SU_Financial Resources FCU ATM - Allentown CVS_2020-04-13-164728.xlsx")
sul<-tbl_df(SU)
su2<-select(sul,"Carrier Name","Account Type (BCH/COM/ATM/FED)")%>%
  filter("Carrier Name"=="BRINKS")
```

Comment: You may need backquotes for `Carrier Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that "Carrier Name" is evaluated literally as a string instead of a column name.  We may need to backquote as there are spaces in the column name

```
library(dplyr)
select(sul,"Carrier Name","Account Type (BCH/COM/ATM/FED)")%>%
        filter(`Carrier Name` =="BRINKS")
```

Or use `filter_at` with `vars`

```
select(sul,"Carrier Name","Account Type (BCH/COM/ATM/FED)")%>%
      filter_at(vars("Carrier Name"), all_vars(. == "BRINKS"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help